# Multiple partial dependence plots in one graph

Tags: r, plot, partial

I am using the `randomForest` package with the `Partialplot function`.

I want to make multiple partial dependence plots in one graph. My thesis promotor told me that it is possible to save them (in the environment, I did this and I got a list object with 'x' and 'y' variables in that list), but I don't know how to recall the graph after saving it.

What I want to do is:

**1.** Save PD plots

**2.** recall them

**3.** plot multiple PDP in one graph

Comment: If `randomForest` uses base graphics, (ie. grid is not required) then take a look at the `layout` function: `?layout`.

Comment: Base graphics are not "recall-able". If you use grid graphics (lattice or ggplot) then you save the graphics call to an named object. You should post a sample dataset and the code that does something similar to what you have acheived so far and then be clearer about what you want. It's possible you will need to determine the eventual ranges for the final plot and set xlim and ylim values along the way to allow accurate overlays. All depends on the details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `partialPlot` function, consider using the `plotmo` function in the [plotmo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotmo/index.html) package.  This will draw plots for all variables and variable pairs on a single page. For example:

```
library(randomForest)
data(trees)
mod <- randomForest(Volume~., data=trees)
library(plotmo)
plotmo(mod, pmethod="partdep") # plot partial dependencies
```

which gives

[image: plot]

You can specify exactly which variable and variable pairs get plotted using plotmo's all1, all2, degree1 and degree2 arguments. Additional examples are in the [vignette for the plotmo package](http://www.milbo.org/doc/plotmo-notes.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pdp` package. Examples are given in the paper: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-016/RJ-2017-016.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect!  Can save the plots as lattice objects and then recall.  Plot together using `gridArrange` or `CowPlot` and pretty them up using `ggplot`.  Great solution!